# Connect OLED SSD1306 to Elegoo Uno R3

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm trying to connect the [OLED SSD1306](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBtYQ.jpg) screen to my Elegoo Uno R3 and display something using Arduino IDE. However, nothing shows up on the screen for some reason.

I have connected every pin in the following way:

- VCC: 3.3V
- GND: GND
- SCL: A5
- SDA: A4

You can see the setup in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

Then, I'm using the code from [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-for-oled-display-with-arduino/), that is, [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiSantosdotme/Random-Nerd-Tutorials/master/Projects/OLED/oled_adafruit_demo.ino), to see if the setup is correct, but nothing shows up on the screen. My question is: does anybody know if this is right way to do it? Even though I'm using analog pins and the screen needs digital ones, [I read online](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) that it doesn't matter:

> The analog input pins can be used as digital pins, referred to as A0, A1, etc. The exception is the Arduino Nano, Pro Mini, and Mini’s A6 and A7 pins, which can only be used as analog inputs.

I also saw in [Elegoo Uno R3's guide](https://epow0.org/%7Eamki/car_kit/Datasheet/ELEGOO%20UNO%20R3%20Board.pdf) that the A4 and A5 pins are used for the I2C protocol, which is the one that this OLED screen uses:

[image]

So as far as I know, from the hardware point of view, everything seems to be correct, right?

Comment: Did you check that your code uses the correct I2C address for your particular OLED display? If you're not sure about the address, you could run the I2C scan example sketch to find it. You can find it in the Arduino IDE in Examples->Wire->WireScan.

Comment: @StarCat Yes, it's the 0x3C address: `Scanning... I2C device found at address 0x3C! done`

Comment: Did you need to change any parameters in the sample code to match your display e.g. SCREEN_HEIGHT ?

Comment: Many of these modules have their own onboard 3.3V regulator. You appear to power it from 3.3V while the tutorial you cited is powering it from 5V. Perhaps it "works" enough with 3.3V minus regulator-dropout to respond to I2C but not enough to actually light the display.

Comment: Well, I found one of my own displays with similar (not same) looking design, which I can see has a regulator. It didn't seem to care whether it was powered it from 5V or 3.3V. Worked with your code in both cases.  I don't know how definitive that is though. **If** yours is a type designed to operate with 5V into VCC I would still try it. I wouldn't have used the colors where you did, but I don't see anything technically wrong with your wiring.  My display also responds to 3C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Looks like you have a run-of-the-mill, clone [not Adafruit], 128x64 LCD with / I2C interface.

1. Determine the I2C address by flipping it over and seeing which side a 0 ohm resistor or solder blob is on - either 0 or 1. If it is on the '0' side, the address is 0x3C if it is on the '1' side, it is 0x3D.

Here is a photo of the back and with the address of 0x3c.

[image]

If the back of yours looks very different, locate and run an I2C device scanner to find the address of your display.

2. Do not use the code that you linked.

From the Arduino IDE, install or update the the Adafruit SSD1306 library, Version 2.57 is what I used to test this.

Once the library is in place, load the example SSD1306_128X64_I2C

Locate this line (near the beginning of the code):

#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3D ///< See datasheet for Address; 0x3D for 128x64, 0x3C for 128x32

Change 0x3D to 0x3C if you need to (as determined earlier). I don't think it is an Adafruit screen, so you can ignore the comment.

3. Triple check your 4 connections

Run demo and audibly gasp - "cool".

PS: Mine works on either 3.3V or 5V